# How to get routing to work in HapiJS + Angular?

Tags: angular, hapi.js

I have read different threads and all answers there seem to not work properly, I am just trying to setup a hapijs server which is serving an angular application.

The index.html + other relevant files from ng build lie under the folder ./public. Now in the server.js I do this:

```
server.route({
method: 'GET',
path: '/{param*}',
handler: {
  directory: {
    path: Path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
    redirectToSlash: true,
    index: true,
  }
}
});
```

This works well, but only for localhost:3000/ and if you do anything below (localhost:3000/admin for example) it will respond with a 404, which makes sense, cause there is no /admin in the public directory.

I have also tried:

```
server.route({
method: 'GET',
path: '/{param*}',
handler: {
  file: './public/index.html'
}
});
```

Which does not work, as now the files under /public are not found anymore as they are also routed to the index.html.

Then I have tried to route /public/param* to the directory and /param* to index.html, hoping that now the public files would be "read" properly, but that didn't work as well.

What can I do to get this to work? I feel like I should have found 100 threads getting this to work, but I didn't see a single example which worked for me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have every other route routed to index.html you can create a onPreResponse handler.

```js
'use strict';
const Path = require('path');
const Inert = require('inert');
const Hapi = require('hapi');

const init = async () => {
  const server = Hapi.server({
    port: 3000,
    host: 'localhost',
    routes: {
      files: {
        relativeTo: Path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
      },
    },
  });

  await server.register(Inert);

  server.route({
    method: 'GET',
    path: '/{param*}',
    handler: {
      directory: {
        path: '.',
        redirectToSlash: true,
        lookupCompressed: true,
        index: true,
      },
    },
  });

  server.ext('onPreResponse', (request, h) => {
    const response = request.response;

    if (!response.isBoom) {
      return h.continue;
    }

    if (response.output.statusCode === 404) {
      return h.file('index.html');
    }
  });

  await server.start();
  console.log('Server running on %', server.info.uri);
};

process.on('unhandledRejection', err => {
  console.log(err);
  process.exit(1);
});

init();
```

Comment: Hey, thank you, I’ll check it again. In the example you provided, does it only work if you access / directly or also for subpages? Like if you call localhost:3000/somepage directly?

Comment: It was to early for me, just woke up. I will post an edit, didnt get that you want to have a kind of history api fallback ;)

Comment: Is it a history api callback? If you call / it goes to index.html and then routing will work as the angular app is handling routing then. But if you just go to the site localhost/anyangularpagecomponent (which can happen if someone wants to share links) hapi handles it and doesn’t forward it to index.html, but throws a 404

Comment: With the above edit and the preResponseHandler it will forward now.

Comment: Uff, it works now. The magic was the combination of "files" property in server definition plus catching 404, only one of both won't work. The /admin is unnecessary in this example, maybe we can just take it out as it might confuse people!

Comment: how do you guys compile this code on 2020? I mean I'm on the current version, it won't compile anymore, support for these lib is terrible and I can't find any solution for my problem. this part of the code won't compile anymore if (response.output.statusCode === 404) {
              return h.file('index.html');
            }

Comment: if (response.output.statusCode === 404) {
              return h.file('index.html');
            } it won't compile anymore if somebody knows how to do or what's missing thank you because these JS libraries are horrible in terms of support